# Ros PCL segmentation for dominant plane

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a point cloud of floor and wall. When i did segmentation with plane normals, it gave me plane of the wall instead of the floor as intended. However, when i changed the k search number of kd tree, it gives me the plane of the floor.

My question is 'is there anyway to specify which plane I want to segment?' also' I dont quite understand kd tree search. Please help

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/206728/ros-pcl-segmentation-for-dominant-plane/) by [dmngu9](https://answers.ros.org/users/21514/dmngu9/) on ROS Answers with karma: 150 on 2015-04-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The solution proposed by Stefan suppose your cloud is expressed in a frame where Z points upwards. If the point cloud is expressed in the camera frame, there is no easy way to make the difference between the floor and a wall without more assumptions. If your camera is pointing to the floor you could choose the plan intersecting the optical axis (Z camera axis).

---

Originally posted by [Guido](https://answers.ros.org/users/279/guido/) with karma: 514 on 2015-04-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dmngu9](https://answers.ros.org/users/21514/dmngu9/) on 2015-04-07**:
I wrote a node to capture 1 point cloud to pcd file from the kinect. I dont know if the point cloud is expressed in camera frame or not but I did check the z axis is depth. Can you suggest any method please?

**Comment by [dmngu9](https://answers.ros.org/users/21514/dmngu9/) on 2015-04-25**:
ok. i understand what you said now. however, i want to convert my point cloud in camera optical depth frame to base_link frame. base link is my static tf publisher